# References in Java Inheritance Examples

Tags: java, inheritance, super

```
public class Test1 {

    int a;
    int b;

}

public class Test2 extends Test1 {

    public int c;

    Test2(int a,int b,int c){

        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;      
        this.c=c;}
}


public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test2 test1 = new Test2(3,4,5);
        Test1 test = new Test1();

        test=test1;  //This line is true
        test1=test;  //This line is false

    }

}
```

I couldn't understand even though I looked at the example in the book. How is it possible?Why ı got compile error at "test1=test" line? Can someone explain it?

Comment: How can a line be _false_? What do you mean?

Comment: By "true" and "false" do you really mean "compiles" and "doesn't compile"?

Comment: `Test1(1,2);` Test1 doesn't have that constructor, how could this even compile?

Comment: false means compile error

Comment: Please post the **exact** code you are running.

Comment: Think of it like this: `test1` IS A `test` (because of inheritance) but `test` IS NOT a `test1`.

Comment: because superclass reference variable can point to a subclass object but reverse is not true.
Meaning, you are allowed to do this: Test1 obj = new Test2 but Test2 obj = new Test1 is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

The rules for *assignment conversion* (which is what happens when the value of an expression is assigned to a variable) are spelled out in [section 5.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2). In particular, it is always legal to assign a reference type to a *wider* reference variable:

> A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type *S* to any reference type *T*, provided *S* is a subtype (§4.10) of *T*.

In your case, since `test` is of reference type `Test1`, it is legal to assign anything that is of type `Test1` **or any subtype of `Test1`** to `test`. However, since `test1` is of type `Test2`, it is not legal to assign it an expression of type `Test1`, since `Test1` is not a subtype of `Test2`. In particular, the expression `test` is of type `Test1` and `Test1` is not a subtype of `Test2`.

Note that this is a compile-time check and is independent of the type of the actual value that `test` would have at run time. If you are sure that the expression is actually of the narrower type, you can use a cast:

```
test1 = (Test2) test;
```

However, this will raise a `ClassCastException` at run time if the actual value of `test` is not of type `Test2` (or a subtype of it). So when doing such casts, you lose some of the benefit of compile-time type checks. It is common to use the `instanceof` operator to check that the cast will succeed. However, if you find yourself programming like this, it's a "code smell": an indication that your code design may be deficient in some way.

A similar thing happens with primitive values:

```
int x = 1;
byte y = 2;

x = y; // okay
y = x; // ERROR -- requires a cast to narrow the type
y = (byte) x; // okay
```

Unlike with reference types, casts of primitive types will never throw a `ClassCastException`.